# How to repair towel rack that was anchored in drywall

Tags: repair, drywall, anchor, drywall-anchor

I live in an apartment and my towel rack was ripped out of the wall. I put some weight on it, and one of the sides came out. I looked into the hole and found that it was anchored into the drywall, so maybe it wasn't very secure in the first place. I would like to learn how to fix this on my own instead of having my apartment management fix it, but I'm not sure where to learn how to do this. I would not like to take the other anchored side out that the pole was attached into as that side is still anchored and at a location I like. Is there a way I can re-anchor and reattach this?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Those are [molly bolts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molly_(fastener)), and often aren't too strong. The bigger problem is you'll have to patch the wall well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jab saw to enlarge the hole. Then use a rod of wood and place it behind the spot your towel rack will eventually sit. (Make sure the piece of wood is longer than the towel rack bracket). Screw through the drywall above where the towel rack bracket will sit and below it. This will anchor the wood to the back of the wall while you patch the hole. Once that is done you can patch the hole with a pathig kit (ex.  https://www.amazon.com/Wall-Doctor-Drywall-Patch-2)

Once you have let that set and cure you can remount your towel rack bracket. U can remove the extra screws and patch those holes over with a little spackling.